# NotificationCenter inside my own class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to set an observer for notifications inside my own class.

Let us say we have something like below for example,

```
public class MyClass {

  var center: NotificationCenter

  public init() {
    center = NotificationCenter.default
  }

  public run() {
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(test), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
  }

  func test() {
    Print("TESTED!")
  }
}
```

and in my `ViewController`,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let myClass = MyClass()
  myClass.run()
}
```

then this actually won't work if I tap `textField` or something to make the keyboard up.

The `NotificationCenter` certainly works if I do this without using `MyClass`, or if I change the object registering as an observer like below:

```
center.addObserver(ViewController.self, selector: #selector(test), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
```

and then of course I should implement my `test` function inside the `ViewController` as a `class function`.

But this isn't the way that I want. Any suggestions or advices that would explain why this isn't working?

Comment: Did you try wit textfield begin delegate?  myClass.run()

Comment: @karthikeyan I'm not actually trying to work with `textfields` and `keyboard` notifications, I just gave them as examples since they're pretty common. So no need to workaround for the same behavior. I'm actually trying to observe `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `myClass` will be destroyed at the end of `viewDidLoad`. Because there is nothing references to it. You should create a property in ViewController:

```
var myClass: MyClass?

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  myClass = MyClass()
  myClass?.run()
}
```